# Aliases for commands with Python cmd module

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I create an alias for a command in a line-oriented command interpreter implemented using the `cmd` module?

To create a command, I must implement the `do_cmd` method. But I have commands with long names (like `constraint`) and I want to provide aliases (in fact, shortcuts) for these commands (like `co`). How can I do that?

One possibility that came to my mind is to implement the `do_alias` (like `do_co`) method and just calling `do_cmd` (`do_constraint`) in this method. But this brings me new commands in the help of the CLI.

Is there any other way to achieve this? Or may be is there a way to hide commands from the `help` output?

Comment: Note that when using Linux/Unix, you should have command completion avaiable (using the `TAB` key).

Comment: Hide commands from `help` with `help_cmd(self): pass`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can overwrite the [`default`](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.default) method and search for a suitable command handler (as already suggested by [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12911826/142637)):

```
import cmd

class WithAliasCmd(cmd.Cmd):

    def default(self, line):
        cmd, arg, line = self.parseline(line)
        func = [getattr(self, n) for n in self.get_names() if n.startswith('do_' + cmd)]
        if func: # maybe check if exactly one or more elements, and tell the user
            func[0](arg)
```

Comment: Don't forget to add return statement like `return func[0](arg)`.

Answer (score 10):

The following solution makes aliased commands share a single help message. It lets you keep all of your aliases in a single easy to edit place, while making documentation much easier.  It checks user input against an alias [dictionary with function values](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182093/why-store-a-function-inside-a-python-dictionary) and overrides both the `default()` (*See [sloth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911327/aliases-for-commands-with-python-cmd-module/12912000#12912000) & [brian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911327/aliases-for-commands-with-python-cmd-module/12911826#12911826)*) and `do_help()` methods.

Here I've made aliases `'c'` and `'con'` execute `do_constraint()`, `'q'` invoke `do_quit()`, and `'h'` invoke `do_help()`.  The bonus of this solution is that `'h q'` and `'help quit'` print the same message.  Documentation for several aliased commands can maintained in a single docstring.

```
import cmd

class prompt(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.aliases = { 'c'   : self.do_constraint ,
                         'con' : self.do_constraint ,
                         'q'   : self.do_quit       ,
                         'h'   : self.do_help       }

    def do_constraint(self, arg):
        '''Constrain things.'''
        print('Constraint complete.')

    def do_quit(self, arg):
        '''Exit the program.'''
        return True

    def do_help(self, arg):
        '''List available commands.'''
        if arg in self.aliases:
            arg = self.aliases[arg].__name__[3:]
        cmd.Cmd.do_help(self, arg)

    def default(self, line):
        cmd, arg, line = self.parseline(line)
        if cmd in self.aliases:
            self.aliases[cmd](arg)
        else:
            print("*** Unknown syntax: %s" % line)
```

Comment: This works really well. Thanks for sharing it. One issue I'm seeing is that custom command completion doesn't work, e.g. a complete_constraint method.

Comment: A workaround: complete_con = complete_constraint. The command and help work the same, but you can have your complete def.

Comment: In default(), you need to return the value from the aliased command. do_quit() won't work without it as cmdloop() needs something that evaluates as True for it to stop.

Answer (score 2):

The docs mention a default method, which you can override to handle any unknown command. Code it to prefix scan a list of commands and invoke them as you suggest for do_alias.

Comment: +1 Yes, this is the right way to do this IMHO. I added a simple [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12912000/142637).